# When I try to cast the DataGrid.ItemsSource to the DataView for the second time, I get an error ("Unable to cast object...")

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I want the rows that the user selects to be deleted.

As far as I know, the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` cannot be removed directly using the `DataGrid.Items.Remove()` method, so I must convert the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` to a `DataTable` and use the `DataGrid.ItemsSource = DataTable.DefaultView` property.
To convert `DataGrid.ItemsSource` to `DataTable`, I tried the following solutions in various situations, and each has advantages and disadvantages (I spent several months researching and testing):

**First solution (I made this by myself):**
`XAML:`

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="BookDataGrid" EnableRowVirtualization="True" VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel" CanUserAddRows="False" BeginningEdit="BookDataGrid_BeginningEdit" RowEditEnding="BookDataGrid_RowEditEnding" HeadersVisibility="Column" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="386" Width="486" Margin="0">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="BookName" Binding="{Binding BookName}" Width="SizeToHeader">
                <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Setter Property="AcceptsReturn" Value="True"/>
                        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource CustomContextMenu}"/>
                        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="WrapWithOverflow"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="BookImage" Width="SizeToHeader">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image x:Name="BookImg" Source="{Binding BookImage}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

`C#:`

```
    public byte[] ImageSourceToBytes(BitmapEncoder BitEncoder, ImageSource ImgSource)
    {
        byte[] Bytes = null;
        switch ((ImgSource as BitmapSource) != null)
        {
            case true:
                BitEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create((ImgSource as BitmapSource)));
                using (var Stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
                {
                    BitEncoder.Save(Stream);
                    Bytes = Stream.ToArray();
                }
                break;
        }
        return Bytes;
    }
    public DataTable DataGridToDataTable(DataGrid DG, DataTable DT, byte NumberOfColumns, byte VisualColumnIndex, string ControlName)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < DG.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            DT.Rows.Add(DG.Items[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < DG.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            for (byte j = 0; j < NumberOfColumns; j++)
            {
                switch (j == VisualColumnIndex)
                {
                    case true:
                        FrameworkElement FE = DG.Columns[j].GetCellContent((DataGridRow)DG.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i));
                        Image Img = new Image() { Source = ((((DataGridTemplateColumn)DG.Columns[j]).CellTemplate.FindName(ControlName, FE) as Image).Source) };
                        DT.Rows[i][j] = ImageSourceToBytes(new PngBitmapEncoder(), Img.Source);
                        break;
                    default:
                        DG.ScrollIntoView((DataRowView)DG.Items[i]);
                        DT.Rows[i][j] = ((DG.Columns[j].GetCellContent(((DataGridRow)DG.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i)))) as TextBlock).Text;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        return DT;
    }
```

Advantage: Even if one of the columns is of the `Image` type, this approach operates without an error.

Disadvantage: The method `DG.ScrollIntoView((DataRowView)DG.Items[i])` must be used when the `EnableRowVirtualization` attribute is set to `True`; otherwise, a `null` error will occur. For large numbers of rows, this approach is incredibly sluggish (e.g., if we have 20,000 rows, it could take an hour or more).

**Second solution (I made this by myself):**

`XAML:`

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="BookDataGrid" EnableRowVirtualization="False" CanUserAddRows="False" BeginningEdit="BookDataGrid_BeginningEdit" RowEditEnding="BookDataGrid_RowEditEnding" HeadersVisibility="Column" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="386" Width="486" Margin="0">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="BookName" Binding="{Binding BookName}" Width="SizeToHeader">
                <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Setter Property="AcceptsReturn" Value="True"/>
                        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource CustomContextMenu}"/>
                        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="WrapWithOverflow"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="BookImage" Width="SizeToHeader">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image x:Name="BookImg" Source="{Binding BookImage}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

`C#:`

```
    public DataTable DataGridToDataTable(DataGrid DG, DataTable DT, byte NumberOfColumns, byte VisualColumnIndex, string ControlName)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < DG.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            DT.Rows.Add(DG.Items[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < DG.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            for (byte j = 0; j < NumberOfColumns; j++)
            {
                switch (j == VisualColumnIndex)
                {
                    case true:
                        FrameworkElement FE = DG.Columns[j].GetCellContent((DataGridRow)DG.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i));
                        Image Img = new Image() { Source = ((((DataGridTemplateColumn)DG.Columns[j]).CellTemplate.FindName(ControlName, FE) as Image).Source) };
                        DT.Rows[i][j] = ImageSourceToBytes(new PngBitmapEncoder(), Img.Source);
                        break;
                    default:
                        DT.Rows[i][j] = ((DG.Columns[j].GetCellContent(((DataGridRow)DG.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i)))) as TextBlock).Text;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        return DT;
    }
```

Advantage: This solution converts `DataGrid.ItemsSource` to `DataTable` faster than the first because `EnableRowVirtualization` is equal to `False` in this case.

Disadvantage: This solution consumes a lot of memory; for example, if we have 100,000 rows and the database table is 2GB in size, it will consume 2GB of `RAM` and a `RAM` space error may occur.
[image: After-running-the-App]

**Third solution:**

`XAML:`

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="BookDataGrid" EnableRowVirtualization="True" VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel" CanUserAddRows="False" BeginningEdit="BookDataGrid_BeginningEdit" RowEditEnding="BookDataGrid_RowEditEnding" HeadersVisibility="Column" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="386" Width="486" Margin="0">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="BookName" Binding="{Binding BookName}" Width="SizeToHeader">
                <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Setter Property="AcceptsReturn" Value="True"/>
                        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource CustomContextMenu}"/>
                        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="WrapWithOverflow"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="BookImage" Width="SizeToHeader">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image x:Name="BookImg" Source="{Binding BookImage}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

`C#:`

```
    uint[] BookCodeSelectedItems = null; //I need this for further calculations
    private void DataGridDeleteMenu_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (BookDataGrid.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            case true:
                List<object> DefaultRow = new List<object>();
                DataTable BDT = ((DataView)BookDataGrid.ItemsSource).ToTable(); //The first time the event is executed, no error occurs, but the second time the error occurs on this line
                for (int i = 0; i < BookDataGrid.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    DefaultRow.Add(BookDataGrid.Items[i]);
                }
                BookCodeSelectedItems = new uint[BookDataGrid.SelectedItems.Count];
                for (int i = 0; i < BookDataGrid.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
                {
                    BookCodeSelectedItems[i] = uint.Parse(BDT.Rows[i][3].ToString());
                    DefaultRow.Remove(BookDataGrid.SelectedItems[i]);
                }
                BookDataGrid.ItemsSource = DefaultRow;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Advantage: The `DataGrid.ItemsSource` is rapidly changed to `DataTable` in this approach when the `DataGridDeleteMenu PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event is fired for the first time.

Disadvantage: However, when the event is re-run, a `System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List 1[System.Object]' to type 'System.Data.DataView'.'` error occurs.

**I tested the following code (I put a breakpoint):**

```
var dataType = BookDataGrid.ItemsSource.GetType().BaseType;
```

**Result:**

**For the first time:**

> **Value=** {Name = "MarshalByValueComponent" FullName = "System.ComponentModel.MarshalByValueComponent"}

> **Type=** System.Type {System.RuntimeType}

**For the second time:**

> **Value=** {Name = "Object" FullName = "System.Object"}

> **Type=** System.Type {System.RuntimeType}

It seems that only the *value* has changed.

**But why?**

**And what is the solution?**

[image: Error]

I use the following tools:

`XAML:`

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:DatabaseDataSet x:Key="Database_DataSet"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="BookTableViewSource" Source="{Binding BookTable, Source={StaticResource Database_DataSet}}"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="MemberTableViewSource" Source="{Binding MemberTable, Source={StaticResource Database_DataSet}}"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource BookTableViewSource}" Width="486" Height="386">
    <DataGrid x:Name="BookDataGrid" HeadersVisibility="Column" EnableRowVirtualization="True" VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="486" Height="386" Margin="0">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="BookName" Binding="{Binding BookName}" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Publisher" Binding="{Binding Publisher}" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Category" Binding="{Binding Category}" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="BookCode" Binding="{Binding BookCode}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Inventory" Binding="{Binding Inventory}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ReleaseDate" Binding="{Binding ReleaseDate}" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="DateTaken" Binding="{Binding DateTaken}" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ReturnDate" Binding="{Binding ReturnDate}" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="RecipientName" Binding="{Binding RecipientName}" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Language" Binding="{Binding BookLanguage}" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Length" Binding="{Binding Length}" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Form" Binding="{Binding Form}" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Translator" Binding="{Binding Translator}" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Narrator" Binding="{Binding Narrator}" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ISBN" Binding="{Binding ISBN}" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Location" Binding="{Binding Location}" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Price" Binding="{Binding Price}" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="BookImage" Width="SizeToHeader">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image x:Name="BookImg" Source="{Binding BookImage}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

`C#:`

```
    public void BookDatagridRefresh()
    {
        DatabaseDataSet Database_DataSet = ((DatabaseDataSet)TryFindResource("Database_DataSet"));
        DatabaseDataSetTableAdapters.BookTableTableAdapter BookTable_TableAdapter = new DatabaseDataSetTableAdapters.BookTableTableAdapter();
        BookTable_TableAdapter.Fill(Database_DataSet.BookTable);
        BookDataGrid.ItemsSource = Database_DataSet.Tables["BookTable"].DefaultView;
    }
```

`Visual Studio 2017` `.NET Framework 4.5.2` `WPF`

[image: Binding]

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: DataView has property Table.. which can be used for retrieve the source dataTable
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.table?view=net-6.0

Comment: The best approach is to create a DataTable. Bind this DataTable to the DataGrid.ItemsSource. Now when the user modifies the table he implicitly modifies the underlying DataTable. He can even delete the rows by himself. If you need to read or modify the DataGrid, you don't access it directly, but the underlying DataTable. You do this e.g. to sort, group, read or write. This solution doesn't require to allocate extra memory. It doesn't depend on rendering details like virtualization. It doesn't require any casting. It doesn't require a direct reference to the DataGrid. It's clean and efficient.

Comment: Long story short: your data source must be a DataTable that you store in a public property as binding source for the DataGrid. Always handle the data source (DataTable in your case) instead of handling the data view (DataGrid in your case).

Comment: Thank you for your attention and feedback. I have updated my question (I added an image and some code). As you can see in that image, my database is "MS Access." Now my question is how to bind the "DataGrid.ItemsSource" property to two data sources, i.e., "DataBaseDataSet" and "DataTable".

Comment: If my country's banks were not sanctioned, I would give a gift to the individual who answered this question (I've been looking for an acceptable response for months).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution that does not have the above problems.

I made a strategic mistake. When we connect `DataGrid.ItemsSource` to `DataView` or `CollectionViewSource.Source` for the first time, the values of `DataView` and `CollectionViewSource.Source` change automatically with each change (like insert, edit, and delete), so the code that connects `DataGrid.ItemsSource` to `DataView` or `CollectionViewSource.Source` does not need to be rewritten.

Look carefully at the image below to get a better understanding of how this feature works. When `DataGrid.ItemsSource` changes in the first window, `DataGrid.ItemsSource` in the second window also changes.
[image: DataGrid]

I tested the following codes in different situations, using nearly the entire capacity of the `MS Access` database.

The conditions are as follows:

Number of records = 252,500

Database size = 2,094,128 KB (database size without any rows = 604 KB)

Size of each row = (`Database` size - database size without any rows) / Number of records => about 8.291184 KB (Of course, if I haven't made a mistake)

Hardware and software used in the test = `Acer Aspire 5750G Laptop (Core i5 2nd Gen/4 GB RAM/Win7-x64)`, `Visual Studio 2017`, `.NET Framework 4.5.2`, `WPF`

`XAML:`

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:DatabaseDataSet x:Key="Database_DataSet"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="BookTableViewSource" Source="{Binding BookTable, Source={StaticResource Database_DataSet}}"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="MemberTableViewSource" Source="{Binding MemberTable, Source={StaticResource Database_DataSet}}"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource BookTableViewSource}" Width="486" Height="386">
    <DataGrid x:Name="BookDataGrid" HeadersVisibility="Column" EnableRowVirtualization="True" VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="486" Height="386" Margin="0">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="BookName" Binding="{Binding BookName}" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Publisher" Binding="{Binding Publisher}" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Category" Binding="{Binding Category}" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="BookCode" Binding="{Binding BookCode}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Inventory" Binding="{Binding Inventory}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ReleaseDate" Binding="{Binding ReleaseDate}" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="DateTaken" Binding="{Binding DateTaken}" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ReturnDate" Binding="{Binding ReturnDate}" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="RecipientName" Binding="{Binding RecipientName}" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Language" Binding="{Binding BookLanguage}" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Length" Binding="{Binding Length}" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Form" Binding="{Binding Form}" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Translator" Binding="{Binding Translator}" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Narrator" Binding="{Binding Narrator}" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ISBN" Binding="{Binding ISBN}" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Location" Binding="{Binding Location}" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Price" Binding="{Binding Price}" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="BookImage" Width="SizeToHeader">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image x:Name="BookImg" Source="{Binding BookImage}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

`C#:`

```
    public DataView BDV = new DataView();
    object[] BookCodeSelectedItems = null;
    object[] ISBN_Value = null;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BDV = BookDataGrid.ItemsSource as DataView; //In "XAML" or "C#," binding is only necessary once
    }
    private void DataGridDeleteMenu_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (BookDataGrid.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            case false:
                MessageWindow MW = new MessageWindow();
                MW.YesButton.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                MW.NoButton.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                MW.MessageLabel.Margin = new Thickness(0, 110, 0, 0);
                MW.MessageLabel.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                MW.Image.Source = GetImageFromBytes(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + @"\Images\Warning.bin"));
                MW.MessageTextBlock.Text = "No rows selected";
                MW.OKButton.Content = "OK";
                MW.ShowDialog();
                break;
            default:
                var stopwatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
                stopwatch.Start();
                List<object> Row = new List<object>();
                //Additionally, I tested the "AddRange" function of the "List<>" and it appeared to be one second slower. I mean "Row.AddRange(BookDataGrid.Items.Cast<object>().ToList());"
                for (int i = 0; i < BookDataGrid.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    Row.Add(BookDataGrid.Items[i]);
                }
                BookCodeSelectedItems = new object[BookDataGrid.SelectedItems.Count]; //I need this for further calculations
                ISBN_Value = new string[BookDataGrid.SelectedItems.Count]; //I need this for further calculations
                int j = 0;
                foreach (DataRowView DRV in BookDataGrid.SelectedItems)
                {
                    BookCodeSelectedItems[j] = BDV.Table.Rows[BDV.Table.Rows.IndexOf(DRV.Row)][3];
                    ISBN_Value[j] = BDV.Table.Rows[BDV.Table.Rows.IndexOf(DRV.Row)][14];
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < BookDataGrid.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
                {
                    Row.Remove(BookDataGrid.SelectedItems[i]);
                }
                BookDataGrid.ItemsSource = Row;
                stopwatch.Stop();
                MessageBox.Show("Total seconds: " + stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString());
                break;
        }
    }
```

Output:
[image: Output]

I also tried the following code, it was very slow. It took more than **10 minutes** and I stopped the app. But `List<>` took about **16 seconds**.

```
        var stopwatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        for (int i = BookDataGrid.SelectedItems.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            BDV.Table.Rows.Remove(((DataRowView)BookDataGrid.SelectedItems[i]).Row);
        }
        BookDataGrid.ItemsSource = BDV.Table.DefaultView;
        stopwatch.Stop();
        MessageBox.Show("Total seconds: " + stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString());
```

I hope this is the most comprehensive solution for converting `DataGrid.ItemsSource` to `DataTable`, `DataView` or another type of data source.

Thank you for your attention.